# Connect to Win CE device From WPF/Win Form Application Without Installing Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce, corecon

I am developing a tool to view information, Files and folders of wince device in WPF. I am able to connect, Disconnect and View Folder structure by following sample from this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2007/12/06/corecon-api-part-v.aspx?Redirected=true).

Everything works fine on developer machine. My machine is Windows XP and I am using VS2008.But when I take WPF exe and run it on a machine where only .net framework installed I am not able to connect to device. Then I installed .net Compact Framework 3.5, and followed same steps provided in link except i don't have visual studio installed on that deployed machine.

Please provide me steps to connect to device without installing Visual Studio. And Am not sure whether it will connect to device without visual studio. So please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreCon is installed by Visual Studio, and is not available separately.

If you want to manipulate the device's file system from your PC, and the device is connected using ActiveSync/Windows Mobile Device Center, you can use the Remote API, RAPI. If you want to use C#, you can use the [OpenNETCF Desktop Communication Library](http://rapi.codeplex.com/), which wraps up RAPI.